# Admin Portal >> Exception on clicking Stores > Settings > Configuration>Advanced and choose System

Tags: magento2.2.4

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): An element with a "system_cron_template_schedule_generate_every" ID already exists.

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): An element with a "system_cron_template_schedule_generate_every" ID already exists.

```
#1 Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->addElement(&Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Text#000000006e60ec97000000001b2423a6#, false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Data\Form\AbstractForm.php:159]
#2 Magento\Framework\Data\Form\AbstractForm->addField('system_cron_temp...', 'text', array('name' => 'groups[cron][gro...', 'label' => 'Generate Schedul...', 'comment' => '', 'tooltip' => '', 'hint' => '', 'value' => NULL, 'inherit' => true, 'class' => '', 'field_config' => array('id' => 'schedule_generat...', 'translate' => 'label', 'type' => 'text', 'sortOrder' => 10, 'showInDefault' => 1, 'canRestore' => 1, 'label' => 'Generate Schedul...', 'validate' => 'validate-zero-or...', '_elementType' => 'field', 'path' => 'system/cron/temp...'), 'scope' => 'default', 'scope_id' => '', 'scope_label' => &Magento\Framework\Phrase#000000006e60e338000000001b2423a6#, 'can_use_default_...' => false, 'can_use_website_...' => false, 'can_restore_to_d...' => true, 'disabled' => false, 'is_disable_inher...' => false), false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset.php:214]
#3 Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset->addField('system_cron_temp...', 'text', array('name' => 'groups[cron][gro...', 'label' => 'Generate Schedul...', 'comment' => '', 'tooltip' => '', 'hint' => '', 'value' => NULL, 'inherit' => true, 'class' => '', 'field_config' => array('id' => 'schedule_generat...', 'translate' => 'label', 'type' => 'text', 'sortOrder' => 10, 'showInDefault' => 1, 'canRestore' => 1, 'label' => 'Generate Schedul...', 'validate' => 'validate-zero-or...', '_elementType' => 'field', 'path' => 'system/cron/temp...'), 'scope' => 'default', 'scope_id' => '', 'scope_label' => &Magento\Framework\Phrase#000000006e60e338000000001b2423a6#, 'can_use_default_...' => false, 'can_use_website_...' => false, 'can_restore_to_d...' => true, 'disabled' => false, 'is_disable_inher...' => false)) called at [vendor\magento\module-config\Block\System\Config\Form.php:382]
#4 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->_initElement(&Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field\Interceptor#000000006e60e636000000001b2423a6#, &Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset#000000006e60ec95000000001b2423a6#, 'system/cron/temp...', '', '') called at [vendor\magento\module-config\Block\System\Config\Form.php:316]
#5 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->initFields(&Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset#000000006e60ec95000000001b2423a6#, &Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Group\Proxy#000000006e60e01c000000001b2423a6#, &Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Section#000000006e60e00c000000001b2423a6#) called at [vendor\magento\module-config\Block\System\Config\Form.php:256]
#6 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->_initGroup(&Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Group\Proxy#000000006e60e01c000000001b2423a6#, &Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Section#000000006e60e00c000000001b2423a6#, &Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset#000000006e60ecd8000000001b2423a6#) called at [vendor\magento\module-config\Block\System\Config\Form.php:302]
#7 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->initFields(&Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset#000000006e60ecd8000000001b2423a6#, &Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Group\Interceptor#000000006e60e01d000000001b2423a6#, &Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Section#000000006e60e00c000000001b2423a6#) called at [vendor\magento\module-config\Block\System\Config\Form.php:256]
#8 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->_initGroup(&Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Group\Interceptor#000000006e60e01d000000001b2423a6#, &Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Section#000000006e60e00c000000001b2423a6#, &Magento\Framework\Data\Form#000000006e60ecd4000000001b2423a6#) called at [vendor\magento\module-config\Block\System\Config\Form.php:202]
#9 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->initForm() called at [vendor\magento\module-config\Block\System\Config\Form.php:542]
#10 Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form->_beforeToHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1110]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1115]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:675]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:566]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('system\config\fo...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:542]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('system\config\fo...') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('system\config\fo...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('system\config\fo...', true) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('system\config\fo...', true) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:522]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('form') called at [vendor\magento\module-config\view\adminhtml\templates\system\config\edit.phtml:32]
#20 include('D:\Albi\xampp\ht...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php:71]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Edit#000000006e60e363000000001b2423a6#, 'D:/Albi/xampp/ht...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Api\InlineUtilInterface\Proxy#000000006e60edf4000000001b2423a6#, 'secureRenderer' => &Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer\Proxy#000000006e60edf2000000001b2423a6#, 'escaper' => &Magento\Framework\Escaper#000000006e60e73f000000001b2423a6#)) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php:273]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('D:/Albi/xampp/ht...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php:303]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\module-backend\Block\Template.php:141]
#24 Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1111]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1115]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:675]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:566]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('system.config.ed...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:542]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('system.config.ed...') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('system.config.ed...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('system.config.ed...', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('system.config.ed...', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('admin.scope.col....', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col....') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col....') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('admin.scope.col....', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('admin.scope.col....', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.col', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.col') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.col') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.col', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.col', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.contai...', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.contai...') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.contai...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.contai...', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.main.contai...', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.content') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.content', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#62 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#63 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#64 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#65 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#66 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', false) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#67 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('backend.page', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:594]
#68 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:544]
#69 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:206]
#70 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:497]
#71 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true) called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:193]
#72 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root') called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout.php:963]
#73 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php:492]
#74 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php:258]
#75 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000006e60e53a000000001b2423a6#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php:171]
#76 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000006e60e53a000000001b2423a6#) called at [generated\code\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php:193]
#77 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000006e60e53a000000001b2423a6#) called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php:120]
#78 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:24]
#79 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:263]
#80 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000006e60e521000000001b2423a6#) called at [index.php:39]
```

[image][image]

Comment: Hi @Sushismita, is this a new Magento installation? Do you have any extra-modules installed? It seems to me that there is a duplicated field value somewhere, but the error you provided doesn't give that information. This could be an external module: could you please confirm whether you have installed any external modules?

Comment: Hi PauGNU we have installed only Omnivore external extension and nothing apart from that.

Aprt from that we have two custom modules. How can we identify. Please advise.

Comment: When we don't know where to look for, the best way is to disable extensions 1 by 1, clean cache and recompile and then check if the issue is still there. Start disabling the Omnivore extension. You should do this tests in a test platform (I know it might be evident, but just in case I prefer to mention it).

Comment: Hi @PauGNU I found the issue that my custom cron group and cron jobs are creating this exception.

But unable to find the root cause with the cron settings.

I ahve attached the screenshots. Would you please advise? Thanks heaps for your help.

Comment: Hi @PauGNUI have fixed the issue by adding <schedule_generate_every>1</schedule_generate_every> in the custom cron group. Thanks